# Difference between hyperledger fabric native setup and hyperledger fabric docker version setup?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am new to hyperledger fabric and I have confusion in native binaries   and docker images.

when we deploy HLF on Kubernetes it require configuration file in yaml and this yaml file need some specification to start docker container service and need fabric image from docker hub which should mention in "containers" section on yaml file. however as in native version we need to setup core.yaml and orderer.yaml file for configuration of peer and orderer binary which is not needed in docker version. why there are no configuration file like core.yaml and orderer.yaml in docker version.

What is the purpose of having both native binary and docker image? Are these completing each other or just providing alternatives to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you mentioned native binary and docker version image in question is [those code](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/7d44ebc84a700061483639454f0d5c5e95e4c7eb/Makefile#L28). The simplest way to get to know you question is check the code.

Both binary and docker image could be maked from the [Makefile](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/7d44ebc84a700061483639454f0d5c5e95e4c7eb/Makefile):

```
docker: $(patsubst %,$(BUILD_DIR)/image/%/$(DUMMY), $(IMAGES))

native: peer orderer configtxgen cryptogen idemixgen configtxlator discover
```

Check the make command in that file, you will find the native binaries pass from pre-built executables, which is used for building docker image in Makefile.

```
peer: $(BUILD_DIR)/bin/peer
peer-docker: $(BUILD_DIR)/image/peer/$(DUMMY)
```

If it is easier to understant: These more like dependencies rather than alternatives. The docker version of peer, which startup command is `peer node start`, more likes a entity of `peer` binary.

Besides, if you `docker exec` into the docker version hyperledger fabric, you will find there are core.yaml or orderer.yaml in `/etc/hyperledger/fabric`. We do need to setup configuration on docker image. There are two ways:

1. mount self-configurated `core.yaml` to its location on container.
2. More common: setup `environment` on your k8s yaml file. e.g. startswith `CORE_PEER_` or `ORDERER_GENERAL_` etc.

Leave comment if you still confuse.

Answer (score 0):

1. The docker containers have binaries installed in it.
2. The dockerised version doesn't require the core.yaml or orderer.yaml
   unless you want to self mount it with your custom environment
   variables. generally the environment variables which are defined in
   the yaml files are present in the docker compose file in the
   environment section.

if still confused then do comment.

Comment: Hi,how I will self Mount core.yaml and orderer.yaml into docker?

Comment: I have Answered that in this link hope it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56819137/where-to-include-core-yaml-in-hyperledger-fabric/56820397#56820397