# Where to include core.yaml in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am working on Hyperledger fabric and trying to retrieve historical transaction records from the network. So, i found **core.yaml** config to enable ledger historic database. But, i don't find where to include the "**core.yaml**" in the application source repository.

I found few clues to add the file in **docker-compose.yaml** as

**CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=core.yaml**

So, is it the correct way of adding the "**core.yaml**" in the **docker-compose.yaml** file.?

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '2'
services:

ca.org1.example.com:
image: ${FABRIC_DOCKER_REGISTRY}${FABRIC_CA_FIXTURE_IMAGE}:${ARCH}${ARCH_SEP}${FABRIC_CA_FIXTURE_TAG}
hostname: ca.org1.example.com
environment:
  - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.org1.example.com
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/0427fbe1849b3e146f05201e1d8c5e570337faaaa19ed37deda69bb7c88c71ef_sk
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CFG_AFFILIATIONS_ALLOWREMOVE=true
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CFG_IDENTITIES_ALLOWREMOVE=true
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=7054
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=false
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/0427fbe1849b3e146f05201e1d8c5e570337faaaa19ed37deda69bb7c88c71ef_sk
ports:
  - 7054:7054
expose:
  - 7054
command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/0427fbe1849b3e146f05201e1d8c5e570337faaaa19ed37deda69bb7c88c71ef_sk -b admin:adminpw -d'
volumes:
  - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config


 couchdb.peer0.org1.example.com:
image: ${FABRIC_DOCKER_REGISTRY}${FABRIC_COUCHDB_FIXTURE_IMAGE}:${ARCH}${ARCH_SEP}${FABRIC_COUCHDB_FIXTURE_TAG}
hostname: couchdb.peer0.org1.example.com
environment:
  - COUCHDB_USER=admin
  - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=adminpw
ports:
  - 5984:5984
expose:
  - 5984

 peer0.org1.example.com:
image: ${FABRIC_DOCKER_REGISTRY}${FABRIC_PEER_FIXTURE_IMAGE}:${ARCH}${ARCH_SEP}${FABRIC_PEER_FIXTURE_TAG}
hostname: peer0.org1.example.com
environment:
  - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/var/hyperledger/tls/server.key
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/var/hyperledger/tls/server.crt
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/var/hyperledger/tls/ca.crt   
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_SKIPHANDSHAKE=true
  - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
  - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
  - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
  - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/var/hyperledger/msp
  - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=info
  - CORE_LOGGING_CAUTHDSL=warning
  - CORE_LOGGING_GOSSIP=warning
  - CORE_LOGGING_LEDGER=info
  - CORE_LOGGING_MSP=warning
  - CORE_LOGGING_POLICIES=warning
  - CORE_LOGGING_GRPC=error
  - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_SHIM=info
  - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
  - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
  - CORE_CHAINCODE_BUILDER
  - CORE_CHAINCODE_GOLANG_RUNTIME
  - CORE_CHAINCODE_EXECUTETIMEOUT=120s
  - CORE_PEER_NETWORKID=multiorgledger
  - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=admin
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=adminpw
  - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
  - CORE_VM_DOCKER_ATTACHSTDOUT=true
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb.peer0.org1.example.com:5984
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_SERVERHOSTOVERRIDE=peer0.org1.example.com      
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org1.example.com:8051      
working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
command: peer node start
volumes:
  - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
  - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/msp
  - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls:/var/hyperledger/tls
  - core.yaml:/var/hyperledger/config
ports:
  - 7051:7051
  - 7053:7051

 couchdb.peer1.org1.example.com:
image: ${FABRIC_DOCKER_REGISTRY}${FABRIC_COUCHDB_FIXTURE_IMAGE}:${ARCH}${ARCH_SEP}${FABRIC_COUCHDB_FIXTURE_TAG}
hostname: couchdb.peer1.org1.example.com
environment:
  - COUCHDB_USER=admin
  - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=adminpw
ports:
  - 6984:5984


 peer1.org1.example.com:
image: ${FABRIC_DOCKER_REGISTRY}${FABRIC_PEER_FIXTURE_IMAGE}:${ARCH}${ARCH_SEP}${FABRIC_PEER_FIXTURE_TAG}
hostname: peer1.org1.example.com   
environment:
  - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/var/hyperledger/tls/server.key
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/var/hyperledger/tls/server.crt
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/var/hyperledger/tls/ca.crt   
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_SKIPHANDSHAKE=true
  - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
  - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
  - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
  - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/var/hyperledger/msp
  - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=info
  - CORE_LOGGING_CAUTHDSL=warning
  - CORE_LOGGING_GOSSIP=warning
  - CORE_LOGGING_LEDGER=info
  - CORE_LOGGING_MSP=warning
  - CORE_LOGGING_POLICIES=warning
  - CORE_LOGGING_GRPC=error
  - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_SHIM=info
  - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
  - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
  - CORE_CHAINCODE_BUILDER
  - CORE_CHAINCODE_GOLANG_RUNTIME
  - CORE_CHAINCODE_EXECUTETIMEOUT=120s
  - CORE_PEER_NETWORKID=multiorgledger
  - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=admin
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=adminpw
  - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org1.example.com
  - CORE_VM_DOCKER_ATTACHSTDOUT=true
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org1.example.com:7051
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb.peer1.org1.example.com:5984
  - CORE_PEER_TLS_SERVERHOSTOVERRIDE=peer1.org1.example.com      
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
command: peer node start
volumes:
  - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
  - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/msp
  - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/tls:/var/hyperledger/tls
ports:
  - 8051:7051
  - 8053:7051
```

Please suggest me some solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO its not.

CORE_VM_ENDPOINT
starts chaincode containers on the same bridge network as the peers.

You can mount the path of the folder containing core.yaml file on the peer container

If you are using fabric samples go to bellow path

> fabric-samples/firest-network/base/

add the bellow code to the volumes section of **peer-base.yaml** if you want all peers to have history enabled OR add to the volumes of selective peers in **docker-compose-base.yaml file**

```
- "Path/to/the/folder/where/core.yaml/exists":/var/hyperledger/config
```

If any doubts do revert.

Comment: Thank you for the info but after adding in volumes section, i got error saying : no declaration was found in the volumes section

Comment: i got it working, just missed ./ while adding core.yaml into the volumes , Thanks

Comment: Its path to the folder where the yaml file is.instead of just adding core.yaml

Comment: the core.yaml file is also at same location as docker-compose.yaml